# Run local wordpress instance from cloned openshift app git repository

Tags: wordpress, git, workflow, openshift

I'm developing plugins for a wordpress application hosted with OpenShift. I can clone the git repository from openshift, and I get a structure like this

```
├── .openshift
│   ├── action_hooks
│   │   ├── build
│   │   ├── deploy
│   │   ├── post_deploy
│   │   └── pre_build
│   ├── config
│   │   └── wp-config.php
│   ├── cron
│   │   ├── README.cron
│   │   ├── daily
│   │   ├── hourly
│   │   ├── minutely
│   │   ├── monthly
│   │   └── weekly
│   ├── languages
│   │   ├── .gitkeep
│   │   └── plugins
│   ├── markers
│   │   └── README
│   ├── openshift.inc
│   ├── pear.txt
│   ├── plugins
│   │   ├── .gitkeep
│   │   ├── myplugin.php
│   │   └── buddypress
│   └── themes
│       └── .gitkeep
├── README
├── README.md
├── libs
│   └── .gitkeep
├── misc
│   └── .gitkeep
└── php
    └── .gitkeep
```

When deploying to openshift with `git push`, it automatically moves things to the correct location on the server.

I want to run a development instance locally and replicate that process. How can I move the plugins, themes, etc to the correct places in wp-content locally in the same way that openshift does on the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you only change `WP_CONTENT_DIR` without changin `WP_CONTENT_URL` as well, chances are you will see a broken themes both in the front-end and back-end. The reason is that WordPress will still fetch the resources from `your_domain/wp-contents/themes/your_theme/` even though now you just already point wp-content to a different folder.

Inspired by [@bcole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3587307/bcole), I've tried an approach with less burden: which is to **put your openshift repo folder under local wordpress folder.**

Here's the steps:

1. Download and unfold the updated WordPress package from [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/)
2. Go inside your wordpress folder: `$ cd wordpress_folder`
3. Cloen your openshift repo from remote:

   `$ git clone ssh://12345678asdf123@your_app-your_domain.rhcloud.com/~/git/your_app.git/`
   (you may get the remote url from your openshift dashboard after login)
4. Initiate your WordPress application locally (you may setup a localhost server and got through classic Wordpress 5 minutes start up process)
5. Modify your `wp-config.php` file in your WordPress folder (not the one in `.openshift/config` folder!)
6. Add these two lines BEFORE `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');` :

   `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/your_app/.openshift');`
   `define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '/your_app/.openshift');`
7. Copy the themes plugins you want to upload to openshift in `your_app/.openshift/`
8. `git add`, `git commit`, and then `git push` to remote
9. All done!

The only difference to [@bcole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3587307/bcole)'s approach is that we now put the openshift INSIDE the wordpress folder, not NEXT TO it. The benefit is that now we can define `WP_CONTENT_URL` in a more decent manner.

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for local development could be to create an instance of WordPress that is configured to look in all the right folders of the project repository without actually moving any of the project structure around. You can achieve this with a combination of symlinks, and wp-config options.

## Possible setup for your project:

#### 1. Create a local WordPress install

Put it anywhere, perhaps next to the main project repo.

```
├── project-repo-checkout
│   └── .openshift, etc
└── wordpress
```

#### 2. Create a special local wp-config.php

Put it in the wordpress directory, or one level up.

You can create a clean wp-config file just for development, or you could do this if you need to use the wp-config in the project repo:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/repo/.openshift');
require('/path/to/repo/.openshift/config/wp-config.php');
```

The option `WP_CONTENT_DIR` tells WordPress to go look in the folder `.openshift` and treat it as if it were the `wp-content` folder. So then it will look for 'themes' and 'plugins' in the `.openshift` folder instead.

## Here is my setup, as another example

I have a git repo for WordPress that looks a bit like this:

```
├── wp-config.php
├── src
│   ├── plugins
│   ├── themes
│   └── other stuff
└── wordpress
    ├──wp-admin
    └──wp-includes
```

Note the wordpress core files are off in their own folder, and all the development stuff is in `src` and `wp-config.php` lives outside of everything and is git-ignored.

This line in wp-config.php tells WordPress to go look in the development folder for everything:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/project/src');
```

And then it will look in 'src' for folders called 'plugins' and 'themes' and it's as if 'src' is now the `wp-content` directory.

Some caveats I learned along the way: It's not possible to symlink the 'themes' or 'plugins' folder because WordPress uses PHP code that checks for the presence of actual directories. It IS possible to symlink the 'uploads' folder though.

Comment: Openshift uses getenv to define some values in wp-config.php, for example,
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
Do you know how I can set these variables locally?

Comment: If `getenv` is not defined as a function locally but it IS used in the wp-config.php file in your project repo, and if you are creating a local wp-config.php file as I described, then you should also be able to define the `getenv` function locally to return whatever values you like. [Here is an example of how that could be done](https://gist.github.com/bcole808/c444f4b3e4bcc8b43b96) so that you can use separate values locally. Does that help?

Comment: If you are using this approach, notice that the path to your repo should be absolute and can not be a symlink to that folder. To make it easier, use `__File__` with `dirname()`. For example, in the case where wordpress folder is a sibling of your openshift repo, your may do something like this:
`define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/your_project/.openshift');` nested dirname means the parent folder of the current `wp-config.php` file